# pyinstallery is not a valid command

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a desktop app from my django app following this tutorial:

http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/Recipe/DjangoApplication

But, I' getting this message:

pyinstallery is not a valid command

I'm tring this on windows 7.

But I already installed pyinstaller with pip and it didn't show an error message.

Comment: is `pyinstallery` a typo in the docs should it be `pyinstaller`?